# Migrate blog to new domain

Tags: wordpress, wpml

The WordPress blog uses the WPML plugin which allows using either separate domains or the same domain and site codes after the main domain.

**I want to change the blog from** :

https://magazine1.example1.fr/ --> https://magazine1.example1.com/fr/

---

https://mag1.compactor.it/ --> https://mag1.example1.com/it/

Can you suggest to me how to do it? Are there any risks?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do a [Database backup](https://wordpress.org/support/article/wordpress-backups/). After that you can move the website to the new host, e.g. https://magazine1.example1.fr/ --> https://magazine1.example1.com/, and then do the WPML setup for the `/fr` language. Also, check how to [change the website URL](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/) to the new one.